# Wav file corrupted header

Tags: audio, wav, audacity

Is there any tool that helps with fixing a .wav file header other than Audacity?

The file is playing pure noise on audacity and doesn't open in other applications at all.

I believe the header is corrupted and not sure which value to use for "offset".

Here is a sample file: [.wav corrupted file download 4 mgb](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/LinxezOplTLlxaX)

Here is another file just to confirm:

[Another corrupted .wav file 35 mgb](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/hVo25i3yw2VGqBB)

Answer (score 1):

To get a grip on an unknown binary file its always good advice to pop it open using a hex editor ... https://www.wxhexeditor.org/

The file looks to be a binary dump of some web page ... notice the right column showing HTML

[image]

or issue this terminal command to render each byte in boolean  and its ASCII counterpart

```
xxd -b name_of_given_binary_file 

00000000: 00111100 00100001 01000100 01001111 01000011 01010100  <!DOCT
00000006: 01011001 01010000 01000101 00100000 01101000 01110100  YPE ht
0000000c: 01101101 01101100 00111110 00001010 00111100 00100001  ml>.<!
00000012: 00101101 00101101 01011011 01101001 01100110 00100000  --[if 
00000018: 01101100 01110100 01100101 00100000 01001001 01000101  lte IE
0000001e: 00100000 00111000 01011101 00111110 00111100 01101000   8]><h
00000024: 01110100 01101101 01101100 00100000 01100011 01101100  tml cl
0000002a: 01100001 01110011 01110011 00111101 00100010 01101110  ass="n
00000030: 01100111 00101101 01100011 01110011 01110000 00100000  g-csp 


od -a name_of_given_binary_file   # octal dump is handy here too

0000000   <   !   D   O   C   T   Y   P   E  sp   h   t   m   l   >  nl
0000020   <   !   -   -   [   i   f  sp   l   t   e  sp   I   E  sp   8
0000040   ]   >   <   h   t   m   l  sp   c   l   a   s   s   =   "   n
0000060   g   -   c   s   p  sp   i   e  sp   i   e   8  sp   l   t   e
```

Comment: Good answer. If I were to make a wild guess, you have downloaded the wave from internet not as wave, but wrapped in html. Happens when you simply "click" instead of right click (context menu) and "save as".

Comment: @LukaszTracewski so right you are ... now that I've reached the download I see Audacity sheds no light ... even with a corrupted header or no header at all and Import -> Raw Data then running through various combinations nothing helps give a recognizable signal ... I'd say its less of an issue of a corrupt header than a corrupt payload ... ffprobe gives a :  000101_0369.wav: Invalid data found when processing input ... aplay says : 
Playing raw data '000101_0369.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono  ... then it sounds like a machine synthesized SDR data transmission

Comment: thanks guys for taking interest. Actually this file is from a recorder a friend has, 70% of the records are corrupted in the same way, while 30% still work. What happens is that the recorder suddenly showed a message asking if it should "correct" the files, and we pressed yes, and then the files were corrupted. it is a 100% not an html file ( although I see the result you got, so I am also confused)

Comment: my mistake I right click downloaded it initially later did the click then download my fault ... however once I examined the wav file no luck